# Rails-Activestorage | Recently added image does not show up when validation error occurs in edit form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

In `edit-form` I changed one of the already-uploaded image. There was some validation error when form is submitted, so the form was rendered back with validation error. But the image I changed recently which was not yet stored to the database did not show up in the browser. I inspected the DOM and found out there was an URL associated with that image but was inaccessible. I mean the URL didnt take me to the image.

### Model

```rb
    class Establishment < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :user
      has_one_attached :avatar
      has_many_attached :images
```

### before updating images i.e

[image: preview images]

---

### After

[image]

---

```
.row.mb-4
  .col-lg-3.col-sm-12
    .row
      .col-12.mb-4
        = image_tag establishment_avatar_url(establishment), class: 'establishment-image img-fluid w-100'
      .col-12
        = f.file_field :avatar, class: 'd-none'
        h2#changeProfile.badge.badge-primary.p-2.margin10top.mb-4
          | Profile Picture
          i.fa.fa-file.ml-2
  .col-lg-9.col-sm-12
    .col-12.border.bg-light.py-3
      h4.col-sm-12.col-md-12 Images
      .col-sm-12.col-md-12.col-lg-12
        = f.file_field :images, multiple: true, class: 'd-none'
        a.add-images.btn.btn-primary.p-2.my-3 href="javascript:void(0)"
          | Add Pictures
          i.fa.fa-file.ml-2
        .col-sm-12.col-md-12.col-lg-12.image-wrapper
          .row.image-row
            - establishment.images.each do |image|
              .col-sm-4.col-md-4.col-lg-4.mb-4
                = image_tag image, class: 'establishment-images img-thumbnail w-100'
                - if image.id
                  = link_to delete_establishment_image_establishment_path(image.id),
                          method: :delete,
                          data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} do
                    i.fa.fa-trash.text-danger.position-absolute.border.border-danger.font-lg
```

---

### Code to load preview image when selected from filesystem

```
var browse = document.querySelector('.add-images');
        var fileObject = document.querySelector('#establishment_images');
        browse.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            fileObject.click();
        });
        fileObject.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {

                var files = event.target.files; //FileList object
                var output = document.querySelector('.image-row');

                for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                    var file = files[i];
                    //Only pics
                    if (!file.type.match('image')) continue;

                    var picReader = new FileReader();
                    picReader.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
                        var picFile = event.target;
                        var div = document.createElement("div");
                        div.classList.add("col-sm-4", "col-md-4", "col-lg-4", "mb-4")
                        div.innerHTML = "<img class='establishment-images img-thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" + "title='" + file.name + "'/>";
                        output.insertBefore(div, null);
                    });
                    //Read the image
                    picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
                }
            } else {
                console.log("Your browser does not support File API");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Sumin James, since there is no way to get access to the actual filepath in the Disk, there seems to be no solution to this. One workaround is to validate the form info via AJAX and then only let browser submit the form. This way, file fields dont have to be flushed.